# I am trying to reduce my code to make it simpler by removing the indexes

Tags: python

This is my recursive function named `find(text,substring)` that will return the substring if the substring is inside the text or return an empty string if substring is not inside the text. Another function named `is_string_there(text, string)` to test the `find` function. The function will return `True` if the string is inside the text or `False` if the string is not inside the text.

Am I able to cancel out text index and substring index to remove the two `(0,0)` at the print coding area to reduce  my code to make it simpler and easier to understand so i can teach my students

```py
def find(text, substring, text_index, substring_index): 
    if text_index == len(text) and substring_index != len(substring): 
        return False

    if substring_index == len(substring): 
        return True

    if text[text_index] == substring[substring_index]: 
        return find(text, substring, text_index+1, substring_index+1) 

    return False


def oo(text, substring, text_index, substring_index): 
    if text_index == len(text): 
        return False


    if text[text_index] == substring[substring_index]: 
        if find(text, substring, text_index, substring_index): 
            return True
        else: 
            return oo(text, substring, text_index+1, substring_index) 


    return oo(text , substring, text_index+1, substring_index)

print(oo("I love pie", "pie",0,0))
print(oo("I love pie1", "pie1",0,0))
```

Comment: I don't understand, why you want to re-implement the `find()` method of string class in a complicated recursive way. Just for learning?

Comment: if substring in string will already do the problem, But I think OP wants to demonstrate recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you use oo() to check if a character matches, and then calls find() to check if the rest of the characters match. Instead of checking character-by-character, you could use the idea of checking string equality. In your oo() function, you can check if the substring is equal to a splice of the original text. This will reduce your code but will make your find() function obsolete, while still serving as a simple demonstration of recursion.

```
def oo(text, substring, index): 
    if index == len(text):
        return False  

    start = index
    end = start + len(substring)  

    if text[start:end] == substring: 
        return True
    else: 
        return oo(text, substring, index+1) 


print(oo("I love pie", "pie",0)) 
print(oo("I love pie1", "pie1",0))
print(oo("I love pie", "pie1",0))
print(oo("I love pie1", "pie",0))
print(oo("pie", "pie",0))
print(oo("pi", "pie1",0))
print(oo("pie1", "pie",1))
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
True
True
False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to remove the indexes permanently from the print commands, you could just use a class. This way you can even create other functions to take user input etc and take advantage of class variables for readability. Not sure if if cases should in form if-elif-else though:

```
class test():    
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.run()
    def reset(self):
        self.substring_index = 0 #instead of putting in function they are now class variables
        self.text_index = 0
    def run(self):#more stuff can be done here

        print(self.oo("I love pie","pie"))
        self.reset() #reset the class variables for each step
        print(self.oo("I love pie1","pie1"))

    def find(self,text, substring): #pretty much the same code just using class variables and class methods
        if self.text_index == len(text) and self.substring_index != len(substring): 
            return False

        elif self.substring_index == len(substring): 
            return True

        elif text[self.text_index] == substring[self.substring_index]: 
            self.text_index +=1
            self.substring_index +=1
            return self.find(text, substring) 

        else:
            return False


    def oo(self,text, substring): 
        if self.text_index == len(text): 
            return False


        elif text[self.text_index] == substring[self.substring_index]: 
            if self.find(text, substring): 
                return True
            else: 
                self.text_index +=1
                return oo(text, substring) 
        else:
            self.text_index +=1
        return self.oo(text , substring)

if __name__=='__main__':
    test()
```

Although just for reference, a super simple way for the problem is actually:

```
def oo(text,substring):
    if substring in text:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

AS mentioned in comments:

```
def oo(text,substring):
    if text.find(substring) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Returns 0 if exists in text, -1 if not.

Interesting expansion possible when considering uppercase or lowercase diffrences. 'A' != 'a'